# Find missing objects in NSSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsset

I have 2 NSSet's, say SetA and SetB.

SetA has 3 objects. `SetA = @[ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC];`

SetB has 4 objects. `SetB = @[ObjectA, ObjectC, ObjectD, ObjectE];`

I wish to find out which objects of SetA are missing in SetB. One way I can do it is by iterating over every object in SetA and finding it in SetB.

Question - Is there a quicker way to achieve this in which I don't have to iterate over the entire set. The sets are dynamically populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NSMutableSet and `minusSet` to remove elements in another set.  The difference is what you're looking for.